# Laravel 5 Model relationships

Tags: laravel-5

I just want to make sure that I am handling my relationships correctly.  In my database, I have foreign constraints set up.  I have a users table and a departments table.  A user can only be apart of one department.  However, a department can have many users.  So in User.php, I have

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department');
}
```

And then in Department.php I have

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Does this represent the relationship I am after?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you experiencing any problems with the relation?

Comment: How about the column name?

Comment: Not experiencing any problems yet.  I just wanted to make sure that a user can only be apart of one department, but departments can have many users.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this  is correct for a one-to-many relationship.

The only thing I would change is `user()` to `users()` as there are "many" users.

Lastly, just make sure that in you users table you have a column called `department_id`, otherwise you will have to tell laravel explicitly which column name you're after.

Hope this helps!